# How to put ID in @Url.Action from AngularJS?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm using AngularJS to display records

```
<tr class="highlight" ng-repeat="sector in sectors | filter:searchText">
    <td>
        {{sector.Name}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to put a link in `{{sector.Name}}` using

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Sectors")">
{{sector.Name}}
</a>
```

The problem is that I don't think can put `{{sector.ID}}` in the `@Url.Action` like this `<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Sectors", new { id = {{sector.ID}} })">`

So is there anyway to use my `sector.ID` in the link?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I found the answer using this

```
<a ng-href="@Url.Action("Details", "Sectors")?id={{sector.ID}}">
```